# Events not firing in StimulSoft JS reports

Tags: events, report, stimulsoft

I’m using StimulSoft JavaScript reporting and I need to make charts in the GroupFooter of my report. I searched for the solution and I came up with the following link:
https://forum.stimulsoft.com/viewtopic.php?&t=5212

I tried it but the events in the report seem to not be working.
I prepared a sample report similar to what I need without the unnecessary data:

In this (attached) report, there is a GroupHeader, a Databand (not assigned), a GroupFooter, a chart in the GroupFooter with constant data and a variable named “myVar” with the initial value of “12”. There is also a TextBox set with `{myVar}` in order to see if the value of variable is changed. In the “before event” of the GroupHeader, the value of variable is changed to “98”. However, in the preview mode the event does not seem to fire and the value of TextBox is not changed.

What am I doing wrong? I checked the similar reports and they went through the same process.
I checked it on [js.stimulsoft.com](http://js.stimulsoft.com) as the latest build.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The events are not supported in Stimulsoft Reports.JS

Comment: Thank you for your response. As you are the technical support representative at Stimulsoft, do you have any plans to add this feature in the next builds? Or is there any other way to create charts in the GroupFooter like in the link I posted?

Comment: We are working in this direction. The creation of the chart could be different and needs more detailed description of your situation.

Comment: What I need is exactly similar to the report created by StimulSoft report .Net in the link above.